# Running a bash script from php webpage

Tags: php, linux, bash

I have a php web page being ran by the apache server, it is stored in `/var/www/myweb/` and called `index.php`

Now I am trying to call a script in `/home/me/` called `test.sh` from the php webpage . All it does is create a file1 on `/home/me/`

**test.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash


touch file1
~                                                                                                     
~                                                                                                     
~                                                                                                     
~
```

inside `index.php`, I am trying to call the script

index.php:

```
  if ($_GET['run'])
                   {
                                          exec('/home/me/test.sh');
                   }
```

unfortunately this is not working, and it seems the reason is permission problems. I went ahead and try to run this command from `/var/www/myweb/`

```
/home/me/test.sh
```

and I got this error:

> touch: cannot touch ‘file1’: Permission denied

Is there a way to fix this problem ?

Comment: depending on your system apache2 server use the user "www-data" or "http" or other settings. The test.sh have to be executable and got the right permissions.

Comment: Do you ever use `cd` or `chdir()` in your scripts? What does `ls -ld /var/www/myweb /home/me` return? Your code probably does not execute where you think it does.

Comment: `drwxr-xr-x 29 me me  4096 Mar 27 21:02 /home/me/
drwxr-xr-x  4 root    www-data 4096 Mar 27 20:22 /var/www/html/
`

Comment: @Amadan this is what it returns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not change a directory, you are *not* trying to touch `/home/me/file1`, but `/var/www/myweb/file1`. However, `/var/www/myweb` permits `root` to `rwx`; `www-data` group to `r-x` and also everyone else to `r-x`. When Apache runs it, it is running it as `www-data`, in `www-data` group; it gets the group permissions `r-x`, which prohibit creating a new file. When you run it, it is running as `me`, presumably not in `www-data` group, which takes the last set of permissions: still `r-x`, still unable to write.

Ideally, you would want to provide the full path to the file being created, to avoid confusion about where in the file system you are, and that location would want to have the permissions `drwxrwxr-x` (or `drwxrwsr-x`) for `me` and group `www-data`.